# Fetch role information of a Perforce branch using P4.Net DLL

Tags: p4.net

I want to fetch role (AD Group) information of a P4 branch using P4.Net. Is there a way to find which AD Group has access to a perticular P4 branch.

Answer (score 0):

P4 Protects command can be used to get role information.

Syntax:

p4 protects [folder/file path]

Above command gives list of all the groups\users who are having access to the p4 folder\file